# What's the difference between VirtualViewManager and FlatViewManager in react native android

Tags: react-native

I am trying to read the code of react native android. What confuses me is the difference between VirtualViewManager and FlatViewManager. As far as my understanding, flatViewManager is used for flat UI implementation. But, what is the puporse of VirtualViewManager? VirtualViewManager and FlatViewManager are very similar to each other, is there any reason why the two similar ViewManager exist together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React, there is a notion of virtual layout node, which is a React node that is not a Flexbox node. It is usually a child of a non-virtual parent and helps the parent get measured and laid out.

The best example is an RCTVirtualText, which holds styling Information, such as font size, text color etc.

For example, examine the following React code:

```
<Text color=green>
  He
  <Text size=11>ll</Text>
  o
</Text>
```

Will actually expand into the following:

```
<RCTText color=green>
  <RCTRawText>He</RCTRawText>
  <RCTVirtualText size=11>
    <RCTRawText>ll</RCTRawText>
  </RCTVirtualText>
  <RCTRawText>o</RCTRawText>
</RCTText>
```

RCTVirtualText and RCTRawText are virtual nodes, they cannot be measured and only exists ąs part of a whole RCTText.

Virtual nodes never map to an Android View (top level RCTText can be mapped to a TextView, but inner virtual nodes will not).

Going back to ViewManagers, since virtual and non-virtual nodes behave differently, their corresponding ViewManagers behave differently, too, and thus have different classes. For example, VirtualViewManager throws an exception from createViewInstance() while FlatViewManager returns a new FlatViewGroup() from the same method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I have other question and I will open another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465546/what-is-the-purpose-of-flatviewmanager-in-react-native-android